# On the increase vs increasing

Tags: phrase-usage

1. That sort of thing is enormously on the increase.
2. That sort of thing is enormously increasing.

I know that the first sentence is grammatically correct.

Is the second sentence correct too? And if yes, is there a difference of nuance between them?

Comment: I would word the second as: _That sort of thing is increasing enormously._ Your version isn't grammatically incorrect, but I think my version would be preferred more often.

Comment: Actually I have seen only your version on the internet, but I worded it purposely this way.

Comment: That's a better question. You should expound upon that.

Comment: Sorry, not much to expound upon that. I just wanted to learn if worded this way is correct too.

Comment: Not much to expound upon? I left a comment saying, "I would say 'increasing enormously', not 'enormously increasing'." You replied, "I worded it purposely this way." I'm saying that you could have added a note in your question: "I know I can say _increasing enormously_, but I am specifically wondering about _enormously increasing_." That would be valuable information, I think, and get more to the heart of the matter. It also would have made this question a more interesting question, in my opinion, and that may have led to more answers or more upvotes.

Comment: "Is the second sentence correct?" is a rather mundane question. "I think _enormously on the increase_ sounds better than _on the increase enormously_, but _increasing enormously_ seems to be more natural than _enormously increasing_. Why does the preferred location of the adverb shift when _increasing_ is changed to _on the increase_?" Now **that's** a fascinating and challenging question I would have pondered for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first sentence of yours. In my opinion, it is not the format frequently used.

About the second sentence, it's what exactly J.R. said.

> That sort of thing is increasing enormously.

That's because adverbs of manner (how something happens - here, how is it increasing? **Enormously**) often go in the end position (that's why J.R. said it's not ungrammatical) **BUT** adverbs ending in *-ly* often go in mid-position.

> I'll be *happily* working in my garden.